# Difference In Maven Dependency Display Structure

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I am observing a difference between how the dependencies are being displayed in eclipse ' Maven Dependencies ' folder. Although the M2_REPO translates to C:\Users\XYZ.m2\repository only but why there is a difference in display structure.

Side Note :- I am having some exception while running Project 1 while Project 2 is working fine both have similar set of dependencies that's why i was validating the dependency structure.

Project 1

```
M2_REPO\io\github\classgraph\classgraph\4.8.143\classgraph-4.8.143.jar
```

Project 2

```
C:\Users\XYZ\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Knox Why is there a difference in representation of Maven Dependency?